# Try and except to test multiple functions for error

Tags: python

So, I am trying to use a try and except statement to see if both functions are able to return one of the preset extensions in the list.

Output if I input "file.zip"

```
Application/zip
image() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

Same error, if I was to do a say like "file.jpg"

What I am wanting to achieve by this is for if it is not able to detect one of the extensions in the list after looping over to throw the error 'application/octet-stream'

I was wanting to attempt to do this outside of each function, instead of making one large function as practice, not sure if that is valid practice or not. Also would like to do it without importing any type of libraries, this isn't meant to have files actually imported into the program just simple practice with looping over a list and detecting if the specific extension is located in the list.

```
def main():
    file = input("File name:")
    image(file)
    application(file)

    try:
        if image() == False:
            raise Exception('application/octet-stream')  # Error is here. 
        if application() == False:
            raise Exception('application/octet-stream')
    except Exception as E:
        print(E)


def image(s):
    split = (s.split("."))
    join_s = (''.join(split[1]))
    image_e = ['jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png']
    for i in image_e:
        if join_s in image_e:
            print("Image/"+join_s)
            return True


def application(s):
    split = (s.split("."))
    join_s = (''.join(split[1]))
    app_e = ['pdf', 'txt', 'zip']
    for i in app_e:
        if join_s in app_e:
            print("Application/"+join_s)
            return True


main()
```

I also tested it by having the file variable, as an argument in the try statement, and it doesn't throw any sort of error if I give it an extension not located in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is that inside your `try` block you are calling `image` (and `application`) with no parameters, when they expect one. You should get rid of the calls to `image` and `application` above the `try` and call them in there instead.

Other issues:

- if the file is not an image, an exception is raised before testing whether it is an application
- your functions don't have a return value when they don't match, which means they return `None`, not `False`.
- the data passed to `raise` is in `E.args`, not `E`
- it's generally bad practice to name variables after functions (`split`)

You could resolve these issues with this code:

```py
def main():
    file = input("File name:")
    try:
        if not image(file) and not application(file):
            raise Exception('application/octet-stream')  # Error is here.
    except Exception as E:
        print(E.args[0])
```

Additionally your functions could be greatly simplified e.g.

```
def image(s):
    image_e = ['jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png']
    ext = s.split(".")[1]
    if ext in image_e:
        print("Image/"+ext)
        return True
    return False
```

Finally I would say that although this is an interesting exercise, it would be better to use a single function for all files, replacing the `image_e` etc. variables with a dictionary e.g.

```
{
 'Image' : ['jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png'],
 'Application' : ['pdf', 'txt', 'zip']
}
```

and then looking up the extension in the values and using the key as the MIME type.

Comment: Awesome, and I just want to say thanks a lot for explaining a lot of things to me and telling me things I could do to simplify it and make it easier, also funny you said interesting exercise as in you think it was... helpful in learning or just funny that I was going about it these ways? I had tried several different things before asking for help and researching through docs and other stack overflow post about the try and except statement.

Comment: Also after, looking over your post some more, and studying it does make a lot of sense, and a lot more readable makes a lot of sense thanks again. ( Lots of rude responses sometimes to beginners )

Comment: @Blue I'm glad it was helpful. I was sincere in saying interesting, it's not how one would normally code this sort of functionality but a good exercise in learning about exceptions. And I'm never rude to beginners - I was one once myself and I know what it's like

Comment: Love to hear that, and glad you thought it was interesting I just wanted the practice working with multiple functions ( I even tried throwing the try and except into a function at one point lol.. figured out real quick that was not what I wanted to do ), and my knowledge on exceptions is really minimal so yeah you helped out a lot thanks a ton once more!